# Sharepoint 2010 - SMTP - How to configure outgoing email for SMTP server outside SP farm?

Tags: 2010, email, smtp

I'm having a bit problem when configuring outgoing email for our SP 2010. We ***already have an exchange email server outside the newly build SP 2010 farm***.

How to configure the outgoing SMTP email for SP 2010, as I only found guidance on configuring outgoing email using smtp in SP farm?

I've tried to enter the IP address for the Outbound SMTP server entry, and also tried to enter the server name (as recognized in our network). But still both ways isn't working. Any clues?

Thank you so much for you help...

Comment: Isn't working? Could you provide more details? Were there errors, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach was the correct one. You just have to enter the name or IP of a reachable SMTP server on your network - you don't have to install SMTP or any other mail service on your SharePoint servers.

I would suggest checking if your can reach this mail server. Telnet from the SharePoint server to port 25 of the target server works best:

```
telnet mailserver 25
```

If you do this from a command prompt and the screen goes black or gives a greeting, that means your command reached the mailserver. To be extra sure, then type:

```
EHLO ME
```

and if you get a response back you're good to go. The next important step is to check if your SharePoint server can relay through this mail server - better ask your mail admins for this info. But if you really like this telnet stuff, you can check it from there:

```
mail from:yourfromaddress@domain.com
```

If you don't get an error message like "relaying denied" you're probably ok.

BTW, the telnet client is not available by default starting Windows 2008, so you have to add it via add/remove features or via PowerShell:

```
Add-WindowsFeature Telnet-Client
```

The whole process looks something like this (my commands are marken in green):

[image]

Comment: Or you could use something like smtp test tool - http://www.simplecomtools.com/productcart/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=5&idcategory=5

Comment: So, basically you need an email server that requires no authentication?